# serializing class to file in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have made a Silverlight app that contain a class and I want to serialize that class to some binaryfile of XML file , Is that possible in silverlight or not? without using WCF service,and how can i do it.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this video. It will help with how to access the local FS.  I would assume the XML serializer is available for Silverlight but I am not certain.

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/local-file-access
For writing to isolatedstorage see this:
http://programming4.us/multimedia/882.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to files with Silverlight. You cannot access the client filesystem for obvious security reasons. If you need some storage on the client you could use the [Isolated Storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-%28silverlight-quickstart%29). And for serializing a class to an XML string or a Stream you could use for example the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class.

Comment: You can write files - if you ask permission first.

Comment: You can access the file system in Silverlight 4+ but there are restrictions on this access.